# How to find if HD is supported by iPad or not

Tags: ios, ipad, video, playback

I am getting in trouble of finding the HD support in iPad. 
Is there any way to find out that HD playback is supported by the iPad or not programmatically.

I read somewhere that HD playback is only supported by retina Display.But later i found that iPad 2 without a retina display is also able to play the HD videos..

So is there any other way to find whether the HD playback is supported or not as it seems like it doesn't relates to Retina display at all.

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by "HD playback".

Comment: High definition video playback support.. 720p and 1080p videos playback..

Answer (score -1):

Every iPad can play 720x1080 Every iPad 3rd generation and above (including mini) can play 1920x1080.

[iPad - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp580)

[iPad (3rd generation) - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp647)

[iPad mini - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP661)

Comment: As per i understand from the technical specifications of iPad. iPad can only play upto 720p of playback not 1080p. 3rd generation and above do seems like supporting the full hd playback.. but not such thing for iPad 1 and 2nd gen.